# Is there any way to assign shortcuts to Nautilus bookmarks?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

I have added several dirs as bookmarks to nautilus and I want to know if there a way to assign keyboard shortcuts to some of them.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to the bookmark while being *within* nautilus or do you want to *open* nautilus at the specific location when you use a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @MarcelStimberg Since the answer(s) below wasn't accepted, I assume *Bauna* was after the former: *within* Nautilus. There's a v [similar / related question open here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284707/in-a-save-as-dialog-whats-the-quickest-way-to-keyboard-navigate-to-tmp), suggestions and answers most welcome!!

Answer (score 6):

You can go into Keyboard Shortcuts and create a new "custom shortcut" as "nautilus ~/Documents".

Comment: The ~ didn't work when I tried this on my Fedora 14 system. I had to specify the full path "/home/.../Documents".

Answer (score 1):

Well, your bookmarks can be found in the file ~/.gtk-bookmarks so you could hack something together but there is no built-in way (according to docs etc)